# How it is possible to dismiss a view from a subtracted subview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Whenever my code gets too big, SwiftUI starts acting weird and generates an error:

```
"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"
```

So I started breaking up my code into `Extracted Subviews`, one of the problems I came across is how to dismiss a view from a subtracted subview.

Example: we have here `LoginContentView` this view contains a button when the button is clicked it will show the next view `UsersOnlineView`.

```
struct LoginContentView: View {
    
    @State var showUsersOnlineView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            self.showUsersOnlineView = true
        }) {
            Text("Show the next view")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showUsersOnlineView, content: {
            UsersOnlineView()
        })
        
    }
```

On the other hand, we have a button that is extracted to subview, to dismiss the modal and go back to the original view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UsersOnlineView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                CloseViewButton()
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct CloseViewButton: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Close the Modal
        }) {
            Text("Close the view")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the sbview the state property that defines if the view is shown.

```
struct CloseViewButton: View {
@Binding var showView: Bool

var body: some View {
    Button(
         ShowView = false
    }) {
        Text("Close the view")
    }
}
```

}

When you use the sub view give it the property

```
CloseButtonView(showView: $showOnlineView)
```

To allow the sub view to change the isShown property it needs to get a binding.

On the presentation mode. I think this only works with Swiftui presentations like sheet and alert.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this scenario is to use `presentationMode` environment variable:

```
struct CloseViewButton: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("Close the view")
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: i tried it on my project, it didn't work for me, my project when you click the close button, it shows you a popup, YES/NO, when i put the code Environment in YES it doesn't close the modal, so is there another solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

So I just made a hack and it works for me though it may not be the best way.

```
struct ImageButtonView: View {
    //in the subview just add a static bool like so..

    static var dismissView = false

    var body: some View {
        //then on the button action just toggle dismissView
        Button {
            ImageButton.dismissView.toggle
        } label: {
            Text("tap me")
        }
    }
}

//then on the view you want to dismiss

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body some View {
        ZStack {
            ImageButton()
        }
        .onChange(of: ImageButton.dismissView) { oldValue, newValue in
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```